# How do I see the output of multiple forked processes simultaneously

Tags: ruby, parallel-processing, fork, multiprocessing

I am using the "fork" option in ruby as follows:

```
pid1 = fork do
  pid1_output = `ruby scrape1.rb`
  puts "#{pid1_output}"
  puts ""
  exit
end

pid2 = fork do
  pid2_output = `ruby scrape2.rb`
  puts "#{pid2_output}"
  puts ""
  exit
end

pid3 = fork do
  pid3_output = `ruby scrape3.rb`
  puts "#{pid3_output}"
  puts ""
  exit
end

pid4 = fork do
  pid4_output = `ruby scrape4.rb`
  puts "#{pid4_output}"
  puts ""
  exit
end

Process.waitall
```

The problem here is that sometimes one of the processes (eg: `ruby scrape1.rb`) might fail or end up returning ginormous amounts of text that cannot be captured in a variable... How do I still simultaneously run 4 processes and see all their outputs in one terminal window in realtime? I understand the order of output might be mushed up but that is alright.. I basically want to re-route the STDOUT and STDERR of each forked process to the main program.. That way I can see what is being scraped by each of my scrapers and follow their progress and errors as they happen.

Comment: how would I go about doing this? Is there any sample code online about Kernel#select? -- apart from ruby doc that is... thanks for your input though.

Comment: Also, the ping pong example on rubydoc did not make much sense for my context.. maybe im misunderstanding what you are trying to point out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fork do
  exec("ruby scrape1.rb")
end

fork do
  exec("ruby scrape2.rb")
end

fork do
  exec("ruby scrape3.rb")
end

fork do
  exec("ruby scrape4.rb")
end

Process.waitall
```

Comment: do i not need "exit" within each fork? I am going to try this and see if it works.. thanks for suggesting exec.

Comment: I added "exit" within each fork anyway.. I do not know if it helps with closing the process but it doesn't seem to change the output in a significant way. Thanks a lot, this really solved my problem!